# Using pandas groupby within a specific tolerance

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data-frame that looks something like this:

```
 N  S     Z
 1  4  2.00
 1  5  2.02
 1  1  3.00
 1  3  4.00
 1  7  1.90
 2  2  3.20
 2  3  2.80
 2  2  1.50
 3  1  2.50
 3  3  2.10
 3  6  3.30
 3  7  3.20
```

For every matching value of N, I want to take the sum of the S values that have a similar Z value (within +/- .1) as the maximum S value. Here's an example of what I want it to do:

```
 N  S 
 1  11
 2  3 
 3  13
```

My thought is to do something like `df.groupby[('N','Z')]('S').sum()` but that won't include the tolerance on Z.

Comment: Please post data as text within the question, not as images. It's easier for people to help you if they don't have to transcribe your data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: For your example data, what threshold did you use? You say `+/- 0.02`, but from the example you provided, it looks like the threshold is `+/- 0.1`.

Comment: Maybe numpy.digitize helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the answer you provided does not match with the description you gave. 
From the description, I hope below code will work:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('N')
Svalues = []
for key, item in grouped_df:
    gd = grouped_df.get_group(key)
    maxS = pd.DataFrame(index=gd.index.values, columns=['max_S'])
    maxS.fillna(0)
    for index, row in gd.iterrows():
        val = row['Z']
        dff = gd.query('-0.10 <= %s-Z <= 0.10' % val)
        maxS.ix[index, 'max_S'] = dff['S'].sum()
    Svalues.append(maxS['max_S'].max())

x = pd.DataFrame(data={'N':list(grouped_df.groups.keys()),
                       'S':Svalues})
print(x)
```

I First, grouped the data-frame by a value of `N`. Now, in each group, I check whether the value of Z is within the tolerance level or not by querying the data frame, and store sum of `S`. At the end get the maximum of the sum of `S`.

Comment: This works! Thank you and sorry for the error, it has been corrected.